# Change attribute of specific filetypes in Windows subfolders

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file

In order to set a new icon (not thumbnail) in a Windows folder all you need an .ini and .ico file. But after that a script is needed to update it somehow and make the icon appear.

So, I am using the script below in a bat file that changes the attributes of all the folders, subfolders and files in them:

```
set startdir=%cd%
ATTRIB +s "%startdir%\*.*" /S /D
```

Now, I want to make it change the attributes only for specific filetypes. In the CMD after changing the directory (`cd C:\Users\Folder`) to one specific subfolder, the following works:

```
for %f in (*.ico) do (ATTRIB +s +r %f /S /D)
```

but in the bat file, that doesn't do anything even if I place the .bat file inside the subfolder:

```
set startdir=%cd%
for %f in (*.ico) do (ATTRIB +s +r %f /S /D)
```

What I am doing wrong?

UPD:
I have tried this:

```
attrib -a -h -r +s *.ico /s /d
attrib -a -h -r +s *.ini /s /d
```

but that doesn't attach the icon for a reason. Do I need to also change the attribute of the folder? And how can I mention the folder without its files in the code?

Comment: Something like this ```for %%f in (%startdir%\*.ico) do (ATTRIB +s +a -r -h %%f /S /D)``` doesn't work

Comment: Why set a variable to hold the same content as `%CD%`, you could just use `%CD%`, or as it's the current directory, neither.

Comment: Why the `for` loop, when you use `attrib /s` anyway? What's wrong with `attrib +s +r *.ico /s /d`?

Comment: [The method I use in my answer here](https://superuser.com/a/1548582/1125492) to create .ink files containing .ico properties does not require any refresh.

Comment: Refresh doesn't change anything. I had tried that too :P But yes, @T3RR0R you are right. What I am trying to do is actually in the link you pasted.

Comment: I want to add something. My code used to work find but it changed the attributes of the PNG and JPG files of the subfolders. Therefore, I couldn't use them in some programs. The code was the following: ```set startdir=%cd%
ATTRIB +s %startdir%
ATTRIB +s "%startdir%\*.*" /S /D```

Comment: @Stephan There are subfolders. So, one parent, children and then grandchildren. Each folder has a unique Icon.ico and desktop.ini file. If I change the attributes of the .ico and desktop.ini to S, it works. But I don't want any other file like images to have this attribute.

Comment: what do you think `*.ico` does?

Comment: @Stephan What do you mean? In order for the folder to have an attached icon you need to change the attributes of the Icon and the .ini file. But the code doesn't work. The only workaround is to change the attribute to +S for every folder and subfolders and files and then change the attributes of the images (any filetype apart from the .ico and .ini basically) to -S. Then I can use the images in the Photo Duplicate finder software without issues.

Comment: What do you think the `/D` option does? It appears to me, from your updated code, that you must have directories with names matching the `*.ico` and `*.ini` globs! Also, what is the reason for clearing the archive attributes from matching items?